# Extract month data from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I originally have dates in string format.
I want to extract the month as a number from these dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2011/11/2', '2011/12/20', '2011/8/16']})
```

I convert them to a pandas datetime object.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I then want to extract all the months.

When I try:

```
df.loc[0]["Date"].month
```

This works returning the correct value of 11.

But when I try to call multiple months it doesn't work?

```
df.loc[1:2]["Date"].month

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df.loc[0]["Date"]` returns a scalar: [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) objects have a `month` attribute, which is what you are accessing.

`df.loc[1:2]["Date"]` returns a series: `pd.Series` objects do **not** have a `month` attribute, they *do* have a [`dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) attribute if `df['Date']` is a `datetime` series.

In addition, [don't use chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). You can use:

`df.loc[0, 'Date'].month` for a scalar

`df.loc[1:2, 'Date'].dt.month` for a series

Answer (score 4):

There are different functions. [`pandas.Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) for converting `Series` filled by `datetimes` and [`pandas.Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.month.html) for converting scalar. For converting `Index` is function [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html), there is no `.dt`.

So need:

```
#Series
df.loc[1:2, "Date"].dt.month

#scalar
df.loc[0, 'Date'].month

#DatetimeIndex
df.set_index('Date').month
```